# Overlaying stripchart on barplot - how to align columns?

Tags: r, graphics

I have a barplot that I have overlaid with a scatterplot using `stripchart`.

```
Barplot(data1means)
stripchart(data1, add=TRUE, vertical = TRUE)
```

However, the points on the scatterplot are misaligned with the bars on the barplot, as shown here:

[image: here].

So how do I alter the spacing of the scatter plot so they match up? As I understand it, `stripchart` doesn't have a `space` or `width` variable like `barplot` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base graphics, you can plot points on top of the bar plot using the `points` function. We get the x-positions of the bars from the bar plot itself. I've also included an alternative approach where the means are plotted with point markers rather than bars:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(1)
dat = data.frame(group=LETTERS[1:5], y=rnorm(25,20,2))

# Assign the barplot to x so that x will contain the bar positions.
x = barplot(tapply(dat$y, dat$group, FUN=mean), ylim=c(0,1.05*max(dat$y)), col=hcl(240,100, 70))
points(rep(x, table(dat$group)), dat$y[order(dat$group)], pch=21, bg="red")

plot(rep(1:length(unique(dat$group)), table(dat$group)), 
     dat$y[order(dat$group)], pch=21, bg="blue",
     ylim=c(0,1.05*max(dat$y)), xlim=c(0.5,5.5), xaxt="n")
points(1:length(unique(dat$group)), 
         tapply(dat$y, dat$group, FUN=mean), 
         pch="\U2013", cex=3, col="red")
axis(side=1, at=1:5, labels=LETTERS[1:5])
```

[image]

Here's a version of the same two plots using ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(group, y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", fill=hcl(240,100,50)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal()

ggplot(dat, aes(group, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", pch="\U2013", 
               size=8, colour="red") + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, max(dat$y))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]